# What is the most campsite-dense route between Belgium and the Tatras?

Tags: germany, road-trips, camping, poland, tatras

We would like to hike in the Tatras this summer. Due to our kids we can't drive there in one go and would probably like to just take the easy route. Google maps gives us [three options](https://www.google.be/maps/dir/Antwerpen/Tatra/@50.8603511,7.9447449,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c3f9cfba28b153:0x99dc29b1c9f3fb7d!2m2!1d4.4731932!2d51.2145255!1m5!1m1!1s0x473e063930ddd181:0xb2a5cfb08dad3698!2m2!1d20.2436194!2d49.4440136).

Given that we don't have reservations en route and we don't know how much km we will cover per day it would be nice to be able to follow a route covered with camp sites to spent the night.

What would be the best route to take between Belgium and the Tatras to have quite some certainty in finding camp sites to spent the night?

Answer (score 8):

The ADAC provides a [nice map](http://maps.adac.de/) that allows for route calculation, but also displays all the campsites along a route. I checked your route from Antwerps to the Tatra national park and basically, the campsites along the route are so dense that it doesn't really matter:

[image]

In Poland, there is basically every 50 to 100 kilometres a camping site directly next to the high way. In Slovakia and the Czech Republic, the density is quite similar, while in Germany, the density seems to be even higher. So I wouldn't worry too much and choose the route based on other criteria such as sights along the way or huge highway construction sites which you can also check on the ADAC map.